# Can't get css, js files in admin after deploying keystonejs app. What should i do to make it work?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Example here http://clevercontent.org/keystone/signin

How should i deploy it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with RAM on my server on DigitalOcean. I don't have anough RAM to successful `npm install`. So i make `npm install` on local machine and moved `node modules` on server.

**DON'T DO THIS**

`npm install` must to be run on server. Because your node.js libs should be compiled by same C++ library.
So i extend SWAP on server and this is solve problem with `npm install`